# get data using zkemkeeper.dll in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i get data from attendence machine (CL2000) by using zkemkeeper.dll in .net(c#)..iam successfully added refrence zkemkeeper.dll to my project.
here is my code for connection but it return false..

```
zkemkeeper.CZKEM macobj = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
                    bool status = false;
                    string ipaddress = "192.168.1.101";
                    int port = 4370;
                    status = macobj.Connect_Net(ipaddress, port);
                    if (status == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(" Not Connected");


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the preferences of the zkemkeeper.dll reference to "Embed Interop Types" to false.

That's because you zkemkeeper.dll is an old COM Technology.